# Tychonoff space with unique compactification and 3 disjoint non-compact closed subsets

Tags: general-topology

Prolog : The only compactification of a non-compact normal space $S$ is the one-point (Alexandroff) compactification IFF whenever $A,B$ are disjoint closed subsets of $S$, at least one of $A,B$ is compact.(Example. $\omega_1$ with the $\epsilon$-order topology.) In Engelking,General Topology, it is shown that $[(\omega+1) \times (\omega_1+1)]\backslash \{(\omega,\omega_1)\}$ is not normal, which generalizes verbatim, replacing $\omega$ and $\omega_1$ with,respectively, infinite cardinals $a,b$ where $cf(b)>a.$ I showed that the only compactification of $T=[(\omega_1+1)\times (\omega_2)]\backslash \{(\omega_1,\omega_2)\}$ is the Alexandroff. Now if $A,B,C$ are pairwise-disjoint closed subsets of $T$ then at least one of them is compact, although $\{\omega_1\}\times \omega_2$ and $\omega_1 \times \{\omega_2\}$ are disjoint,closed, and not compact. QUESTION: Is there a non-compact Tychonoff space $X$ whose only compactification is the Alexandroff, such that $X$ has $3$ or more pairwise disjoint closed non-compact subsets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y=(\omega+1)\times(\omega_1+1)\times(\omega_2+1)$, and let $X=Y\setminus\{\langle\omega,\omega_1,\omega_2\rangle\}$. The sets

$$\begin{align*}
&\{\omega\}\times\{\omega_1\}\times\omega_2\;,\\
&\{\omega\}\times\omega_1\times\{\omega_2\}\;,\text{ and}\\
&\omega\times\{\omega_1\}\times\{\omega_2\}
\end{align*}$$

are pairwise disjoint, closed, non-compact subsets of $X$. The same kind of argument that shows that the one-point compactification of the Tikhonov plank is its Čech-Stone compactification works for $X$ as well.

Comment: Duh.Why didn't i think of that.Thanks. BTW, can a non-locally-compact space have a unique comp'n?

Comment: @user254665: Good question. The answer is *no*: see Exercise $\mathbf{3.12.16}$ in Engelking.

Comment: Thank you for that..........

Comment: @user254665: My pleasure.

Comment: Now I also have 2 downvotes with no explanations. Love it.

Comment: @user254665: Well, at least it gave me an opportunity to come back and upvote the question, as I ought to have done in the first place!

Comment: You made my day.